# Clear stock browser cache?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, stock-browser

I'm trying to do some css / javascript changes to a webpage with the android stock browser.

How does one clear the stock browser cache, on the Samsung galaxy s3? I've checked settings and settings -> developer settings as well.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the browser by hitting the settings on your phone.

[image: screenshot of browser settings]

Navigate to privacy settings Hit clear cache.

[image: screenshot of 'Privacy and security' settings]

Answer (score 1):

And to continue what Dan wrote, if you mean for the stock Android or Samasung browser (it's not the same app, but it's in the same place), it's what @Dan Hulme answer.

but if the browser is chrome press on the 3 dots > "History" > "Clear Browsing Data.." > pick "Clear the cache", Here is a picture:
[image: Screenshot_1]

**Hope it's been Helpful!**

Answer (score 0):

go to android settings from there select application manager. under the tab "All" scroll down to "Internet".You can find options to clear cache data as well as other data such as saved passwords.etc